# Storing images outside public_html

Tags: php, html, apache, server, localhost

I have a server and would like to store images outside "public_html" folder.

The host is Hostinger.com. The idea is to have a folder "private/uploads" outside "public_html" to store my images. As the images have sensible data, I can't aford to put it public to everyone. My php code correctly uploads the images to the folder

```
$destination = "../private/uploads/" . $name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

But when I try to access it using something like:

```
<img src="../private/uploads/<?= $item['image'] ?>">
```

It doesn't work. Is there a reason for that? Am I not able to store images outside "public_html". Anyone who uses Hostinger had the same problem? Are there any sugestions for securely storing images in a server?

Edit:
I've already tried storing the images in other places, and the only place the images loaded was inside the "public_html" folder.

Comment: Anything outside `public_html` is (barring misconfigurations on your host's part) inaccessible to browsers. As you said, "I can't aford to put it public to everyone."

Comment: Do you know how I can safely store the images without anyone being able to type
    myserver/uploads
and seeing all my images

Comment: Pietro, either nobody can see them or anybody can. The question is, why are you trying to put private images on a public web server?

Comment: @PietroBonfim Depending on *how* sensitive these images are, you could just add an `index.html` file to `myserver/uploads` and there'll no longer be a public *list* of files. If they contain **highly** sensitive info, you should store them outside of `public_html` and control access to them via a script that checks the user's permission to see each specific one, then uses something like `readfile()` to pass it to the browser. If they're *that* sensitive, they shouldn't be on a shared host like Hostinger at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not.
You can still save it into public_html folder change the accessibility to private..

Nobody will be able to access the folder from outside..

to do this you can use htaccess file to restrict all access to the folder.

here is the snippet to do it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)folderName(/|$) - [F]
```

**How to create htaccess file**
very easy! navigate to your Root Folder then create a filename with *.htaccess*

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!